# Assign int values to specific strings

Tags: mysql

Consider the following simple MySQL table:

```
| Answer           |
| ---------------- |
| Extremely likely |
| Likely           |
| Likely           |
| Not a chance     |
| Likely           |
| Potato           |
| Unlikely         |
```

I would like to write a query to SELECT from this table, which **replaces any occurrences** of 'Extremely likely' with 1, 'Likely' with 2, 'Unlikely' with 3 and 'Not a chance' with 4.

All other answers should not be converted.

So the result would be:

```
| Answer |
| ------ |
| 1      |
| 2      |
| 2      |
| 4      |
| 2      |
| Potato |
| 3      |
```

**Can this be done with SQL alone?**

---

After this question was answered I realised I also needed to only do this when another field had a particular value. Here is such a table:

```
| QuestionID | Answer           |
| ---------- | ---------------- |
| how_likely | Extremely likely |
| how_likely | Likely           |
| how_likely | Likely           |
| fave_veg   | Potato           |
```

The query I successfully used for this was:

```
SELECT QuestionID,
    IF(
        QuestionID = 'how_likely',
        CASE Answer
            WHEN 'Extremely likely' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Likely'           THEN 2
            WHEN 'Unlikely'         THEN 3
            WHEN 'Not a chance'     THEN 4
        END,
        Answer
    ) AS Answer
FROM `answers`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE answer
         WHEN 'Extremely Likely' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Likely'           THEN 2
         WHEN 'Unlikely'         THEN 3
         WHEN 'Not a chance'     THEN 4
         ELSE answer
       END As new_answer
FROM   your_table
```

**EDIT:** If you have *lots* of [dynamic] replacements to do then you may find this method too cumbersome to maintain. In these instances you should create a lookup table which you can perform an `OUTER JOIN` to:

```
SELECT Coalesce(lookup_values.new_answer, your_table.answer) As new_answer
FROM   your_table
 LEFT
  JOIN lookup_values
    ON lookup_values.answer = your_table.answer
```

Comment: Lookup table is not a bad idea. I will look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Answer, 'Extremely likely', '1') , 'Likely', '2') , 'Unlikely', '3') , 'Not a chance', '4')
```

Comment: What if there is a value like 'Unlikely, but only on mondays'?

Comment: There would be no problem if you put it in inner paranthese before 'Unlikely' so it will be already replaced with some number and 'Unlikely' wont effect